# "Invariant Violation: Could not find store" even though root is wrapped with <Provider>

Tags: reactjs, npm, redux, react-redux

I am getting this error when I run `npm test` from my react application, and I'm not sure how to fix it. It is telling me to:

> Either wrap the root component in a `<Provider>`, or explicitly pass
>   "store" as a prop to "Connect(App)"

And my root file is already wrapped in a Provider:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import reduxThunk from "redux-thunk";

import App from "./App";
import reducers from "./reducers";

const store = createStore(reducers, {}, applyMiddleware(reduxThunk));

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.querySelector("#root")
);
```

In my App.js file I have this:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import * as actions from "./actions";

import LoginPage from "./components/auth/LoginPage";
import Signup from "./components/auth/Signup";
import Header from "./components/header/Header";
import HomePage from "./components/home/HomePage";

class App extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchUser();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <div>
            <Header />
            <Route path="/" exact component={HomePage} />
            <Route path="/login" component={LoginPage} />
            <Route path="/signup" component={Signup} />
          </div>
        </BrowserRouter>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default connect(null, actions)(App);
```

The error:

```
npm test

> my-app@0.1.0 test /var/jenkins_home/workspace/...
> react-scripts test --env=jsdom

 FAIL  src/App.test.js
  ● renders without crashing

Invariant Violation: Could not find "store" in either the context or props of "Connect(App)". Either wrap the root component in a <Provider>, or explicitly pass "store" as a prop to "Connect(App)".
```

My `App.test.js` file:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";

it("renders without crashing", () => {
  const div = document.createElement("div");
  ReactDOM.render(<App />, div);
});
```

When I run this application locally using `npm start`, no errors are thrown and redux works fine. What's going on?

Note: `npm test` is being run inside of my Jenkins/BlueOcean server pipeline in case that changes something

Comment: Where in your test file is App wrapped in Provider? It is in your root file, but not your test file. what were you expecting?

Comment: @azium clearly my eyes aren't working today :D. thanks